# preg_match_all ignore hyphenated words

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a preg_match_all expression that looks for  + -  and " and breaks words out

```
/[+?-]*"[^"]*"|[+?-]*\b\w+\b/
```

but hyphenated words are causing me problems
if I have smith-cooper then it returns smith -cooper.  i need it to return smith-cooper as one entry.  Also i need -smith-cooper to be returned as one match -smith-cooper and -smith -cooper to return 2 matches -smith -cooper  Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want your regexp to do you only need to replace `\w+` by `[\w-]+` so that your names can include hyphens. `\w` only matches  `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

`/[+?-]*"[^"]*"|[+?-]*\b[\w-]+\b/`

https://regex101.com/r/la5fJg/1

Comment: That works!  Thanks!  I'm not sure if i'm supposed to start a new thread here but I need to keep initials together as well (sorry i just realized this as  a possibility for user input)  smith-cooper, j.y.  needs to be kept as one match where as in the proposed regex they get broken out into matches j and y.  Thanks again for the help!